# on Select getElementDomAttribute method throwing UnsupportedCommandException

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium4

After updating to Selenium 4 -beta-4 I am getting `UnsupportedCommandException` when trying to access Select element (happens on **Remote Run(Linux)**, on Local run everything is ok(MacOs))

Comment: just changed Select usage to sendKeys and it worked, but anyway it just resolve my problem but not Select class problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason was that I used the old version of chromedriver. Now it works well when I use the latest version